# Image with title over top

Tags: views, nodes, media, theming

I am trying to create a view that has a image that is linked to another node, which I can do. However, I want to take the title (of content) and place it over top of the image like this.

[image]

I tried with CSS. Am I missing something?

Comment: My guess is that I will need the title ID within the image ID (css). Maybe rewriting will work?

Comment: Just to clarify. Are you talking about views-module view and is the content title referring to title of the content where the image is saved or title of the linked content?

Comment: View module, Content Title, Content Image

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a Drupal question.

One of the usual methods is to use absolute positioning to remove the title from the document flow. Starting from HTML looking something like (e.g., rewriting with views):

```
<div class="my-frame">
  <img src="my-image.png">
  <div class="my-title">Image title</div>
</div>
```

Then use CSS rules something like:

```
.my-frame { position: relative; }
.my-title { position: absolute; top: 10; left: 10; }
```

Comment: Notice how in this example the position of title is after the image and therefore remains visible when positioned over preceding content. If the title would be before the image the css would need to include also z-index parameter.